# Configuring Listener on Oracle Server

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, configuration, listener

I am very much new to Oracle environment. I was trying to connect to my Oracle server from another machine on the same network. I found out that I need to configure Oracle Listener on the server that I did using the "Net Configuration Assistant" tool.

After saving the configuration file, I opened the `listener.ora` file and saw that in my new listener the hostname is the IP/machine name of the Oracle server itself rather than the client machine, what I was thinking that the host name in the listener should be IP/machine name of the client machine? Is that right?

Comment: Listener listens on db server for incoming connections and has no information on any db clients. On client there is no listener, but you'll need to configure tnsnames.ora file(located usually in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin path) and you need some oracle client software installation. Then in tnsnames.ora you'll write your database sid, ip address/hostname, listener port etc. More info here  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28316/gettingstart.htm#NETAG006

Answer (score 1):

Its clear to me now that the Host name in the listener configuration on the Oracle server is indeed the **IP/Name of the Oracle server** where the database exists and the port number is the port this database will listen to incoming connections. I was wrong in assuming that each incoming connection must be defined as a listener.